# gRPC-web typescript how to convert from long to number

Tags: typescript, grpc, grpc-web

I was working with gRPC-web, and I have data from the server with `id` type `number|Long`.
I need to assign `number|Long` to the `number`. `Long` is from the server that uses gRPC to communicate. 
Error:

```
Type 'number | Long' is not assignable to type 'number'.   Type 'Long' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

When I tried `parseInt()`, it says:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: One of the solution is to put `id: number | Long` to types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long to number is a lossy operation, so you can't do it safely without any precision loss. But there is a .toNumber() method you can use.

https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js